# Reason behind getting stackOverflowError exception?

Tags: java, object, exception

I know this is wrong but I want to know the reason why I am getting

```
 class Student{

     String student;
     int rollno;

     Student stud=new Student("s",20);//(1st object)Thrown exception because of this line

     Student(String student,int rollno){
         this.student=student;
         this.rollno=rollno;
      }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Student stud=new Student("R",101);


    }

    }
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StackOverflowError
at sai.Student.<init>(Student.java:8)
at sai.Student.<init>(Student.java:8).........
```

When I am creating only one object(i.e 1st object) I wont get this error But when I create two object I am getting this error .

Comment: You are not creating two objects. You are trying to create infinite number of objects.

Comment: can you please explain how it creates Infinite objects?

Answer (score 0):

A `StackOverflowError` occurs when an application recurses too deeply and the call stack reaches its limit. In your case, creating an instance of `Student` initializes all its members, including `stud`, which is a `Student` on its own right - so it initializes all its members, including its `stud` and so on until the error is hit.

Answer (score 0):

When a new Student object is created, all it's fields are initialized. 
That means

> String student; 
>        int rollno;
>        Student stud=new Student("s",20);

all happen. The first 2 statements are harmless, but when the 3rd statement is executed, it tries to create a new Student object which results in another initialization of > String student;

> ```
>  int rollno;
>  Student stud=new Student("s",20);
> ```
>
> which again results in another initialization and so on and on until you get StackOverflow Error

Answer (score 0):

```
 Student stud=new Student("R",101);
```

1.First above line is executed and  then the below lines are executed

```
 class Student{

 String student;
 int rollno;

 Student stud=new Student("s",20);
```

2.Since because of Student stud=new Student("s",20) again below lines will get executed and this process continues due to which we get stackoverflowError exception.

class Student{

```
 String student;
 int rollno;

 Student stud=new Student("s",20);
```

**When I am creating only one object(i.e 1st object) I wont get this error But when I create two object I am getting this error .**

**ANnswer:**Since we are not writing anything in main so control wont go to 2nd step

Answer (score 0):

As @Mureinik already mentioned,

```
Student stud=new Student("s",20);
```

Above line is the reason for infinite loop, cause when you are creating instance of `Student` during initializing of member variable `Student` it gets into infinite loop. As its creating objects of its own.

**==Edited==**

There is no point of declaring `Student` type variable as member variable, which I can see. So, you should remove it from its member variable. The final code should look like

```
class Student{

 String student;
 int rollno;

 Student(String student,int rollno){
     this.student=student;
     this.rollno=rollno;
  }

public static void main(String[] args) {
 Student stud1 = new Student("R",101);
 //use  stud instance
 
 Student stud12 = new Student("V",11); // create another instance
 
  }
}
```

Comment: private Student stud; --- due to this line we will get NullPointerException

Comment: @Swati No, you won't. As program starts from main method and OP already initializing stud before using it

Comment: please check ,I tried executing it on IDE I am getting a NullPointerException

Comment: @Swati Then you are doing something wrong. It is not possible to get nullpointer exception until you use before its inialization

Comment: @Swati ohh.. you are the OP. :D

Comment: stud=new Student("R",101);--Even this wont work as Cannot make a static reference to the non-static field stud